# Keeping numlock off in c#

Tags: c#, keyboard

I would like to use the numlock button for something other than numlock.  So basically I would like to turn off numlock when it is pressed and keep it off.  I can capture the button press but it still toggles on/off.   I want it off, always.   Any suggestions?

Not sure WHY anyone would like to know WHY I want this to be done but here is the reason:  I have a bluetooth numeric keypad that I want to use to control a machine.  Does that justify the question?

After a couple hours of research I came across the following code which did the trick:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class SetNumlockKeyOn
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct INPUT
    {
        internal int type;
        internal short wVk;
        internal short wScan;
        internal int dwFlags;
        internal int time;
        internal IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        int dummy1;
        int dummy2;
        internal int type1;
        internal short wVk1;
        internal short wScan1;
        internal int dwFlags1;
        internal int time1;
        internal IntPtr dwExtraInfo1;
        int dummy3;
        int dummy4;
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SendInput(uint nInputs, IntPtr pInputs, int cbSize);

    public static void SetNumlockOn()
    {
        if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock)) return;
        const int mouseInpSize = 28;//Hardcoded size of the MOUSEINPUT tag !!!
        INPUT input = new INPUT();
        input.type = 0x01; //INPUT_KEYBOARD
        input.wVk = 0x90; //VK_NUMLOCK
        input.wScan = 0;
        input.dwFlags = 0; //key-down
        input.time = 0;
        input.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

        input.type1 = 0x01;
        input.wVk1 = 0x90;
        input.wScan1 = 0;
        input.dwFlags1 = 2; //key-up
        input.time1 = 0;
        input.dwExtraInfo1 = IntPtr.Zero;

        IntPtr pI = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(mouseInpSize * 2);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(input, pI, false);
        int result = SendInput(2, pI, mouseInpSize); //Hardcoded size of the MOUSEINPUT tag !!!

        //if (result == 0 || Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != 0)
        // Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pI);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a bunch of customizable shortkeys, why would you use this keyboard feature specificaly ?

Comment: As someone who uses the numpad for the actual numbers, that would sorely irritate me when switching to another app.

Comment: Not to sound rude, but this isn't a place for free code. Rather than just posting a question here, research how you might do this; try it yourself and _then_ if you are having problems with _your_ code, post a question for help. Also, do include your code so that we can see what you've tried.

Comment: Use a keyboard scancode remapper to disable it. Note that NumLock **can** get set by other means, so having the key disabled makes it tricky to change the setting without a numberpad.

Comment: Lol, too broad??   That's rediculous.  It was a simple question.  HOW DO YOU KEEP THE NUMLOCK OFF.  How direct can I be.  I lost 8 points on that?  Maybe I should have said "How do you keep the GREY numlock off??"

Comment: Upvoting as this is a legit question. What's with you "devs".

Comment: Actually found this question useful - no idea why you lost so many points!  I've upvoted it to redress the balance.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example:

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    public const byte VK_NUMLOCK = 0x90;
    public const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
    public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    public static void SimulateKeyPress(byte keyCode)
    {
        keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
        keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool protectKeys; // To protect from inifite keypress chain reactions

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (protectKeys)
            return;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumLock && 
            !(new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Keyboard().NumLock))
        {
            protectKeys = true;
            NativeMethods.SimulateKeyPress(NativeMethods.VK_NUMLOCK);
            protectKeys = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dadde.   I've never lost so many points on what I assumed was a legitimate question.   Thanks for providing and answer and not critiquing why I wanted it answered lol.

Comment: No problem man, not sure why people didnt like your question. Did I solve your problem?

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I get back to my office.  Thanks!